# ReactJs Passing parameters to parent without event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need to pass parameters from child component to parent without event handler like onClick...
My parent component has a method and child component "A" every x second must pass parameters to parent's method. This methods change parent status and pass this value as props to another child component "B".
How can i do this??

this is my code:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            notification: [ {
                data: "-",
                message: "no notification to show",
                type: "-"
            } ]
        };
    },

    handleNotification: function(res) {
        var notification = this.state.notification;
        notification.push(res);
        this.setState({ notification: notification });
    },

    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Child callFunction={this.handleNotification} />
                <NotificationBox
                    notification={this.state.notification}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var Child = React.createClass({
    displayName: "Child",

    handleReturnNotification: function(o) {
        this.props.callFunction.bind(o);
    },

    render: function() {
        var msg = "message:" ;
        var o = {
            data: "-",
            message: msg,
            type: "Alert"
        };
        this.handleReturnNotification.bind(this, o);

        return (
          <div></div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Could I suggest passing a function prop like "onMount" to the child and then having it call that func (if exists) in its componentDidMount.  This is much nicer than executing a callback in the actual render thread.

Comment: Also, if the logic is like you show in your code, this is badly breaking react's top-down methodology.  It would be better to either produce your 'o' object in the parent OR make a static function on the child that you call directly on the parent AND on the child as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the parent method as a props. In child A do `this.props.parentMethod(parameter);`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function to `useEffect()` to fire it during onLoad:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        props.callFunction()
    }, [someVariable]
 );
```